# Laravel : Call to a member function with() on string

Tags: laravel

I'm struggling with Laravel since I'm still a beginner.
In my `web.php` I have the following route

```php
Route::get('/customize/{id}', function ($id) {
    if (User::where('id','=','4')->has('profile'->with('id',$id))->exists() && Profile::where('user_id', $id)->exists()) {
        return true;
    }      
    
    return false;
});
```

I know something isn't right.

Basically what I want to do is, return true ONLY IF **The user with `id` 4 has a profile with the same `id` as the one in the url.**

In my user modal I have the following relationship :

```php
public function profile()
{        
    return $this->hasMany(Profile::class);
}
```

Example of the profiles table:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wr80.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo.

```php
if (User::where('id','=','4')->has('profile'->with('id',$id))->exists() && Profile::where('user_id', $id)->exists()) {
```

Should be

```php
if (User::where('id','=','4')->has('profile')->with('id',$id)->exists() && Profile::where('user_id', $id)->exists()) {
```

By doing `'profile'->with(...)` you were calling a member function (`with(...)`) on a string (`'profile'`).

---

To return `true` only if the User with id 4 has a profile with id = $id, you want to use `whereHas`.

```php
if (
    User::where('id', 4)->whereHas('profile', function ($query) use ($id) {
        return $query->where('id', $id);
    })
    ->exists()
) { ... }
```

Using PHP ^7.4, this can be written a bit more compactly with shorthand Closures.

```php
if ( User::where('id', 4)->whereHas('profile', fn($query) => $query->where('id', $id))->exists() ) { ... }
```

By the way, when using `where()/orWhere()`, if you don't use an operator, it's implied to be `'='` so `where('id', '=', 4)` can be written as just `where('id', 4)`.

Comment: You are right. But the condition seems to not work. Only this portion is executed as it seems `Profile::where('user_id', $id)->exists()`. So the response is true regardless of if the user=4 or not.

Comment: I'll edit my answer. Basically, you want to use `whereHas`

Comment: Working flawlessly ! Thank you very much. Although I don't understand why I had it wrong. Should I used query ?

Comment: I believe `->with('id',$id)` did absolutely nothing. `with()` is for eager loading relationships, not for adding conditions.

Comment: I thought `id` will be receiving the value of the received id .. Anyway thank you again.